# What are the minimum files/config required by a Smart Target enabled deployer?

Tags: smarttarget, deployer

I am setting up Smart Target (2014 SP1) on an existing (Java) deployer, and am in some confusion about what is actually required. There doesn't seem to be the same role distinction that we have with the normal CD API, as far as I can see the installation process and configuration are identical for the deployer and the web application. After installing in my deployer I have:

- Updated `cd_deployer_conf.xml` and `logback.xml` - this makes sense to me
- Additional `smarttarget_conf.xml` - I see I need parts of this, but perhaps not all (`QueryServer` element doesn't seem relevant for example)
- Additional `tld/smarttarget.tl` - not necessary I guess
- Updated `web.xml` - added tag library - again not necessary I guess?
- Additional `smarttarget.referrers.xml` - it seems from the [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-645BDD80-D805-416D-AE74-493E826EB502) that this is not relevant for the deployer
- 22 additional jar files, some of which make sense, but some of which I am unsure are necessary (like 7 google api jars, and 2 ADF cartridge jars)

Is there any way (other than trial and error) to know exactly what the deployer requires as a minimal configuration, and also vice versa, what the web application requires?

Comment: I think you are using SDL SmartTarget 2014 SP1, the Google JARs are for the Content Experiments feature which is introduced in SP1. While the overall question applies for other versions as well, could you still mention the product version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '[Getting Started](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D)' guide in the docs (login required) explains what's required. Although it explains it for a .NET setup, it doesn't differ much.

- smarttarget_conf.xml -> The `<IndexServer>` is the most important one. The `<QueryServer>` isn't used here
- `tld/smarttarget.tl` -> not needed for the deployer AFAIK
- `web.xml` tag-libraries -> not needed for the deployer AFAIK
- `smarttarget.referrers.xml` -> not needed for the deployer AFAIK
- 7 google api jars are only necessary when using `Experiments`. (But not on the deployer, but on your website)
- 2 ADF cartridge jars -> not needed for the deployer. Only for the OData WebService (CMS) and your web-app AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

From experience:

- `smarttarget_conf.xml`: Indeed the QueryServer element is not used on
  the deployer. This is element is in the configuration to keep the
  configuration the same for all web applications (deployer, website,
  CD web service). The documentation does not reveal which elements are required, and the installation media do not have an XML schema for this configuration file.
- `tld/smarttarget.tl`: Only used on the website, this is the TLD
  defining the SmartTarget tags.
- `web.xml`: The deployer does not use any tags, so TLD not needed.
- `smarttarget.referrers.xml`: This is not relevant for the deployer.
  Relevant for website and in some cases the CD web service only.
- `22 additional jar files`: You could not need them all!

  - Skip all JARs
    in the `SmartTarget 2014 SP1\Google Analytics provider` folder on the
    installation media, this includes the Google JARs.
  - You only need the JARs from the `SmartTarget 2014 SP1\Content
    Delivery\java folder`, there are 11 of them. Not sure if you can skip
    one of them in a minimal installation, but I would install them all.

Is this minimal enough? I think the only thing you can shave off this is some third party JARs from the `SmartTarget 2014 SP1\Content Delivery\java folder` on the installation media. But that would be a lot of trial&error and you would keep the risk of running in an unexpected missing JAR issue later.